# Form not submitting through outside button using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form

```
<div id='formdiv'>
<form action='purchase.php' method="POST" id="purchaseform"> 
......

<input type="submit" value="Add Purchase" />
</form></div>
```

After user submits the form..he is first made to confirm the enteries:

```
$('#purchaseform').submit(function(){
    $('#formdiv').hide();
    $('#confirmdiv').show();

return false;   
});
```

where the confirm div is:

```
<div id='confirmdiv'>
data to be confirmed....
<input type="button" value="Confirm" id = "confirmform"/> 
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id = "cancelform"/>


</div>
```

I am trying to submit the form once user clicks on confirm button

```
$('#confirmform').click(function(){
        $('#purchaseform').submit();
        $('#formdiv').show();
        $('#confirmdiv').hide();
    });
```

But the form is not submitting...anyone knows what am i doing wrong here??

Comment: Try `$('#purchaseform')[0].submit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because when you call the `$('#purchaseform').submit();` it will again read your first statement which is

```
$('#purchaseform').submit(function(){
    $('#formdiv').hide();
    $('#confirmdiv').show();
    return false;   
});
```

try using a hidden input to indicate if the datas are confirmed or not. In your form put a hidden textfield

```
<div id='formdiv'>
<form action='purchase.php' method="POST" id="purchaseform">   

<input type="submit" value="Add Purchase" />
<input type="hidden" name="isconfirm" id="isconfirm" value="0" />
</form></div>
```

then in your other statement put a condition before you call `return false` and the other functions

```
$('#purchaseform').submit(function(){
  var confirm = $("#isconfirm").val();
  if(confirm == 0) { 
      $('#formdiv').hide();
      $('#confirmdiv').show();

     return false; }
```

});

then change this as well

```
$('#confirmform').click(function(){
    $("#isconfirm").val(1); //change the value to 1
    $('#purchaseform').submit();
    $('#formdiv').show();
    $('#confirmdiv').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty logical that it's not submitting. After all, whenever it tries to submit, it will instead go to your submit event handler, which always returns false. You have to make sure that if the submit comes from your script instead of from the button in the form, it does submit. One way to do that is like this:

```
var confirmed = false;
$('#purchaseform').submit(function(){
    if (!confirmed)
    {
        $('#formdiv').hide();
        $('#confirmdiv').show();

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        confirmed = false;
        return true;
    }
});

$('#confirmform').click(function(){
    confirmed = true;
    $('#purchaseform').submit();
    $('#formdiv').show();
    $('#confirmdiv').hide();
});
```

This can easily be edited to suit your needs. Another way to do this would be to instead bind the original event to the submit button instead of the actual submit event, but if you do that, you might get into trouble later on if you have a text field in the form and the user presses enter while it's selected. This would then directly submit without confirmation, whereas in the above solution it will neatly ask for a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

you want to have a confirm dialog, first i think that is better to use the jquery ui dialog plugin http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Here is the code to use :

1- add "display:none" to your confirm dialog

```
    <div id='confirmdiv' style="display:none">
     data to be confirmed....
    </div>
```

- delete confirm event

  ```
  $('#confirmform').click ....
  ```

2- init your dialog

```
    $( "#confirmdiv" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Confirm": function() {
               $('#purchaseform').submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

3- Test your code

4- thats all folks

Comment: but how do I put this inside my form submit function..it again will not work. Or I will somehow have to disable submitting of the form by clicking of submit button and pressing the enter key!!

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding what happens when the form gets submitted in

```
$('#purchaseform').submit(function(){
    $('#formdiv').hide();
    $('#confirmdiv').show();

    return false;   
});
```

Instead, how about you use

```
$('#purchaseform').find(":submit").click(function(e){
    $('#formdiv').hide();
    $('#confirmdiv').show();

    return false;
}
```

Or, of course, you can set an ID on the submit button and use that.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your $('#confirmform').submit() function invoke the 1st submit function again.